# How to install rails_admin gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I want to install the RailsAdmin gem.  When I run `bundle install` I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-ui-rails": 
In Gemfile:
    jquery-ui-sass-rails was resolved to 4.0.3.0, which depends on
      jquery-ui-rails (= 4.0.3)

    rails_admin was resolved to 0.6.4, which depends on
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0) Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":   In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.4)

    rails_admin was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      rails (~> 3.1) Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails":   In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 5.0)

    rails_admin was resolved to 0.6.1, which depends on
      sass-rails (~> 4.0)
```

I tried deleting Gemfile.lock and reran `bundle install`, but it didn't work.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox2-rails'
gem "select2-rails"

gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'

gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.10.2'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'bootstrap-material-design'

gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'chewy'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'cells'
gem 'cells-erb'

gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'koala'

gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'htmlentities'

#editor
gem "wysiwyg-rails"

gem 'pundit', github: 'elabs/pundit'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

My Ruby and Rails versions are:

```
* Ruby 2.1.4p265 (2014-10-27 revision 48166) [i686-linux]
* Rails 4.2.4
```

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Interested why rails_admin has gone for 0.6.x when looking at the project they are at 0.8.x.. but in any case I just wanted to advise against blasting bundle install after removing your .lock, or bundle update. That updates everything,  which can break things, and it can make it hard to track down. bundle update the package in question is probably safer.

Comment: in Gemfile specify `gem rails_admin, '0.8.1' and gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '5.0.1'` then try bundle install after remove Ge,mfile.lock

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout [similar issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2214) here. Hope it helps.